# find: missing argument to `-exec`

Tags: shell, sh

I'm trying to get my `Shell` script working, but I keep getting: `find: missing argument to '-exec'`

```
#!/bin/sh
echo Hello World
find ./public_html/var/session/ -type f -name "sess*" -mtime +30 -exec rm -f {} \;
echo DONE
```

I've been trying to find help in these solutions but sadly none of them have solved my problem.
[Shell script - find: missing argument to `-exec'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51859659/shell-script-find-missing-argument-to-exec)
 [find: missing argument to -exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961673/find-missing-argument-to-exec)

Comment: Are you sure the space before `\;` is a real space?

Comment: I've now deleted it and retyped it all myself, still the same.

Comment: Check with `xxd` instead of retyping. Don't you have a MSWin line end after `\;`?

Comment: @choroba I'm sorry but I have no clue how to check that. I'm just trying to make a script that will clean up the files on our Magento server.

Comment: Run `xxd script.sh` and check that the space corresponds to `20` and the newline to `0a`.

Comment: instead, you can - `find ./public_html/var/session/ -type f -name "sess*" -mtime +30  | xargs rm -f`

Comment: Your script almost certainly is using DOS line endings, which means the last argument isn't `\;`, but `\;<cr>`.

Comment: @brokenfoot Thanks that worked just perfect, If you add an answer ill accept it.

Comment: Using `-exec` is preferable to piping to `xargs` for a number of reasons. Did you check if DOS line endings was causing the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option not involving `-exec` is to pipe the result to `xargs` and then `rm` on it:

```
find ./public_html/var/session/ -type f -name "sess*" -mtime +30 | xargs rm -f
```

[man xargs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html)

**Note:**
`xargs` supports executing in parallel with `-P` command, see man page.